# Can we make create Collection in ChromaDB faster?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, chromadb

This is the code for creating collection in ChromaDB:

```
client = chromadb.Client()
collection = client.create_collection(
  name="collection_name",
  metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"}
)
```

and this is for adding data to collection:

```
collection.add(
  documents=a['documents'],
  metadatas=b['metadatas'],
  ids=c['ids']
)
```

Is there a way to speed up this process? I was expecting it to work faster or more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: The thing slowing down was `collection.add()` which had to create embeddings.

If you have already created and stored embeddings, then just input them in the `collection.add()` along with documents, ids, metadata. In this way, the function doesn't have to create embeddings thus saving time.